# UINavigationBar title

Tags: three20, uinavigationbar

I need a custom `leftBarButtonItem` on my navigation bar because I need to perform a function in the view controller when the view is popped. I would like to have the back button have the correct title (of the view controller below). So two questions:

1) Can I get the title of the standard backBarButton item somehow, so that I can manually set my custom button's title?

or

2) Is there another hook/event that I can use that is only called when the user pops the view?

Re 2: I found one solution using:

```
NSArray *viewControllerArray = [self.navigationController viewControllers]; 
int parentViewControllerIndex = [viewControllerArray count] - 2;
```

But this array is (null) for me.

PS I'm using [Three20](http://three20.info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a UIViewController function which gets triggered when the view controller disappears from the screen:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

   .....
}
```

Comment: Your answer is almost right. You still have to do a check:

if (!self.navigationController.topViewController) {
// do you stuff here
}